# Regex that matches a string and not a word

Tags: java, regex, import

I'd like to see what internal libraries are used in my Java project by searching through the code for

```
import com.mycompany.someproject.path.ClassName;
```

Let's say that my project's title is 'myproject'. What regex would match all lines that begin with

```
import com.mycompany.
```

and exclude:

```
myproject.path...
```

Matched lines would be:

```
import com.mycompany.tool.path.SomeClass;
import com.mycompany.sallysproject.path.SomeOtherClass;
```

and exclude all internal project imports:

```
import com.mycompany.myproject.*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import com\.mycompany\.(?!myproject\.).*
```

Explanation:

`import com\.mycompany\.` - The line must start with `import com.mycompany.`. Pretty self-explanatory; note that we need to escape the periods -- `\.` -- so that they actually match periods, and not "any character".

`(?!myproject\.)` - This is called a "negative lookahead". The overall match will succeed only if the pattern inside the parentheses (except for `?!`) does not match.

`.*` - Anything after `import com.mycompany.` (except for `myproject.`) will be matched.